# Workflow for developing for Mongoose queries

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What are some good ways to reduce the time I spend iterating on the development of new Mongoose queries?

Right now, my workflow involves working on a query, waiting for my Node app to restart, calling the API I'm developing, and inspecting the results. That's a lot of overhead for tweaking a query.

Any suggestions for improving this process?

Comment: " involves working on a query, waiting for my Node app to restart, calling the API I'm developing, and inspecting the results." , does that take over 200ms after you update the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use something like [mongooser](https://github.com/aheckmann/mongooser) (a mongoose repl) or just open the node repl yourself, and manually set up mongoose with your schemas/models - play around that way.

Comment: Innnteresting. Thank you, Aaron!

Comment: FWIW, the thing I've been doing for the past day is to have a standalone *.js file + the "piping" module (http://bit.ly/15re7ye). That way I can include minimal dependencies (so it loads faster), and watch the console reload with each file save.